# Apache Tomcat Servlet 404 Troubleshooting

Tags: apache-2.2, tomcat, troubleshooting, servlet, servlets

I maintain a GWT web application that uses 3 java servlets for file download/upload and data transfer.  I had my servlet mapping sin place and have not touched them in months, just a few days ago I started receiving 404 errors when trying to access my servlets.  I can't even seem to access the servlets by typing their full path from the WEB-INF/classes directory (ie /servlet/com/company/project/servletname).

Unfortunately these are running off of a shared hosting plan and I do not have access to starting or stopping tomcat or much of anything else.  Before I issues a trouble ticket with my hosting provider I just wanted to check to see if my assumptions about servlets are correct and to see if there were any steps that I should follow for this type of situation.

Does tomcat need to be restarted in order to use a new servlet uploaded to the "WEB-INF/classes" directory?  Does tomcat need to be restarted to read changes to the web.xml in the "WEB-INF" directory?

If I put a .class file at /WEB-INF/classes/foo/bar.class should I be able to access it immeidately via "http://www.mydomain.com/servlet/foo/bar" or do I need ot wait for tomcat to recognize this new class file?  Or do I have to include it in the existing web.xml servlet mapping file?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Does tomcat need to be restarted in
>   order to use a new servlet uploaded to
>   the "WEB-INF/classes" directory?

It depends, if your

> Does tomcat need to be restarted to
>   read changes to the web.xml in the
>   "WEB-INF" directory?

It depends, if your

> If I put a .class file at
>   /WEB-INF/classes/foo/bar.class should
>   I be able to access it immeidately via
>   "http://www.mydomain.com/servlet/foo/bar"
>   or do I need ot wait for tomcat to
>   recognize this new class file?

No, the class will be available to the webapp classloader immediately, if your context is reloadable, see above.

> Or do I have to include it in the
>   existing web.xml servlet mapping file?

To access your class (assuming it extends HttpServlet) via HTTP, it will need a mapping in `web.xml` (assuming you are using straight http servlets)